# Why "element Index" method for array doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, validation

I'm learning loops and I created my loop program with loopCounter variable. 
Like this

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter++)
```

It finally works! But I went further and wanted to change loopCounter to elementIndex way. And it doesn't work.

**Could you prompt me why? And what code will?** Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userAge = new Array ();
var elementIndex;

for (elementIndex in userAge) {
userAge[elementIndex] = prompt("Enter your age please! ","0" );

   if (isNaN(userAge[elementIndex]))  { 
   alert ("Enter ONLY Number value please! "); 
   }  else   {   
      if (userAge[elementIndex] == 0) {
          alert ("You are a baby");
          } else if ((userAge[elementIndex] <=0) || (userAge[elementIndex] >=130))
            {
             alert ("I think you are lying about your age!");  }
   else {
        alert ("That\'s a good age!");
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

**The code that works**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userAge = new Array ();
var loopCounter = 0;

while (loopCounter >= 0) {
userAge[loopCounter] = prompt("Enter your age please! "+ loopCounter,"0" );
   if (isNaN(userAge[loopCounter]))  { 
   alert ("Enter ONLY Number value please! "); 
   }  else   {   
      if (userAge[loopCounter] == 0) {
          alert ("You are a baby");
          } else if ((userAge[loopCounter] <=0) || (userAge[loopCounter] >=130))
            {
             alert ("I think you are lying about your age!");  }
   else {
        alert ("That\'s a good age!");
        }
   }
loopCounter++;}
</script>
```

Comment: `userAge` is empty, there's nothing to iterate over..? What are you trying to do? You should also use array literal syntax (`[]`) rather than the Array constructor.

Comment: What is `elementIndex`

Comment: I tried to do the same as "in code that works" (added to post) but different way as it was described in my book "Beggining JS 4th edition"
there another way with "for in" loop.

Comment: "Rather than having to work out the index number of each element, the for...in loop does it for you and automatically moves to the next index with each iteration (loop through)." quote

Comment: @RomanTselenko You've got it all wrong. Read [some decent documentation for Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: @RomanTselenko that is not what for..in does

Comment: Read also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration